# in Perl, I want to record data to a file, and then later access this data

Tags: perl

I want to save data inputted from the command line, written in Perl, into a `.txt` file. Then, write the program to check and see if the numbers inputted this time are bigger or smaller then the numbers inputted the last time the program was run.

I don't need any examples, but a link to where I can find a module or method to do this would be nice.

Comment: Take a look at the `Storable` module.

Comment: Storable seems overkill for this. Sounds like he just wants to write a few numbers to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that most of what you want will be in [the tutorial for `open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html).